# Lethal Dose (LD50) for the different factors in a logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have a logistic regression model that contains a continuous variable and a qualitative variable with various levels/factors. Is there a way to calculate LD50 for each of the factors?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggeffects)
library(MASS)

# Produce a table with data
set.seed(321)

x1 <- rnorm(400)
x2 <- 3*x1^3 + 2*x1^2 + x1 + 1
x3 <- 1/(1 + exp(-x2))
x4 = rbinom(400, 1, x3) 

dt <- tibble(binary = x4,
             continuous = x1,
             qualitative = sample(c("white", "pink", "lime"), 400, TRUE))

# Logistic model
mdl <- glm(binary ~ continuous + qualitative, family = "binomial", data = dt)

# Calculate LD50, which gives the lethal dose for the whole model
dose.p(mdl) # -0.58 ± 0.11 se

# Plot regression model by factor of the qualitative variable
newdat <- ggpredict(mdl, terms = c("continuous[all]", "qualitative"))
plot(newdat)
```

How can I calculate LD50 ± SE for each of the factors (LD50 for lime, LD50 for pink, etc.)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This below fits a model for binary vs continuous for every factor and pulls out the LD50 and SE:

```
get_LD50 = function(fit){
   data.frame(
   LD50 = dose.p(fit)[1],
   SE = attributes(dose.p(fit))$SE[,1]
   )
}

dt %>% group_by(qualitative) %>% 
do(get_LD50(glm(binary ~ continuous, family = "binomial", data = .)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   qualitative [3]
  qualitative   LD50    SE
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
1 lime        -0.578 0.115
2 pink        -0.479 0.104
3 white       -0.392 0.116
```

If you would need something actually more complicated on the statistical side, you have to clarify

Comment: Thanks stackoverflow member. That looks like a good approach. However, I should have mentioned (my fault, sorry!) that the continuous variable only takes positive values in the real data. When I apply your function, then two of the LD50 values are negative, which aren't interpretable, as ecologically speaking I can't have a negative value for the continuous variable.

Comment: It has nothing to do with my solution I am afraid. I only use the dose.p function from MASS which does the ld50 calculation from the fit. If you are getting ld50 that doesn't make sense, it's either the wrong fit or your data needs cleaning

Comment: Both of these are outside the scope of this question or SO I am afraid. If you look at the example u provided, the ld50 calculated is correct.